# Select a valid choice. XXXXXXXX is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django

i want to send sms to selected user form multiple choices by admin side but, I am unable to get the values from the `select_users` field after the selection is done by the admin. Please help me to solve this.

here's my code

**forms.py**

```
class SendSMSForm(forms.ModelForm):
    select_users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=SignUp.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    class Meta:
        model = SendSMS
        fields = ['sms_subject','sms_text']
        widgets = { 
        'sms_text': forms.Textarea()
        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SendSMSForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['select_users'].choices = [(str(item.mobile_no), str(item.mobile_no)) for item in SignUp.objects.all()]
```

**admin.py**

```
class SendSMSAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = "admin/sms/SmsMarketing/change_form.html"
    form = SendSMSForm
    list_display = ['sms_subject','sms_text','date1']
    list_filter = ('sms_subject',)
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = SendSMSForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                subject = form.cleaned_data['sms_subject']
                message = form.cleaned_data['sms_text']
                ***users = form.cleaned_data['select_users']***
                print users
                obj = SendSMS()
                for user in users:
                    result = obj.sendsms(message, user)
                    obj_name = User.objects.get(username=user)
                    if result:
                        SmsHistory.objects.create(
                            number=user,
                            recipient=obj_name.get_full_name(),
                            sms_subject=subject, 
                            sms_text=message,
                            sms_type = "Promotional SMS"
                            )                   
            else:
                return SendSMSForm
        return SendSMSForm
```

Comment: Are you changing the options in any point? Django do not allow you to choose a value that is not on the queryset of the field.

Comment: Add `select_users` to `fields = ['sms_subject','sms_text']` and also however in __init__ if you change, then make it like this and try: `select_users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)`

Comment: #Rubico: i am not changing options in any point but i want to get those selected values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

`select_users = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)`

Comment: #trantu: i need choices which is in database so that's why i wrote ModelMultipleChiceField

Comment: @mahendrakamble: You already do it in `__init__` -> `self.fields['select_users'].choices = ...` . But did you tried my proposal?